# Veins simulation,changing bitrate based on distance

Tags: omnet++, veins

I've been working on omnet++ veins to simulate a highway scenario and the relationship between vehicle and RSU(roadside unit).I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically change the bitrate of my RSU setting

```
*.**.nic.mac1609_4.bitrate = 6Mbps
```

Above is the original setting of bitrate,I'm hoping to adjust this value based on the distance between RSU and vehicle.Are there any module I can use to get the distance and furthermore respectively manipulate the bitrate between different vehicle nodes and RSU nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Veins 4.7.1, you can set the modulation and coding scheme (MCS), so - by extension - the bitrate, via a call to [the setMCS method of the MAC layer](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.7.1/src/veins/modules/mac/ieee80211p/Mac1609_4.h#L157). Calculating the distance is supported via a method of the Coord class which is used to represent node positions.

Comment: Sir,in the veins example code,where should I add these module to manipulate the situation I want,should I add a new .cc file?